# Accessing requestor ip and time from spring controller

Tags: java, spring

I need the requestor ip and the time of the request in my spring rest controller. I am using spring 4.0

This is the signature of my controller:

```
public  @ResponseBody ReturnData downloadStart(@RequestBody DownloadStartVO startVO)
    {
.....
}
```

Please tell me what to do. Thanks

EDIT::
These are my dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
 <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       </exclusions>   
</dependency>
<!-- LogBack dependencies --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>                                    
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>                
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>     
    <version>${jcloverslf4j.version}</version>  
</dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId><!--  -->
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.35</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>

  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring + Quartz need transaction -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Quartz framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.13</version> 
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Add the `HttpServletRequest` and use that to get the IP address (`getRemoteAddress`) the time is the current time imho.

Comment: add? to the params? tried autowiring it. Could not find HttpServletRequest in spring

Comment: Well because it is a `javax.servlet` class. `HttpServletRequest` is part of the servlet api. I strongly suggest a read of the MVC chapter of the Spring Reference guide as that explains what you can use as method arguments and which will be mapped automatically by Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following dependency in my pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now I can add the HttpServletRequest parameter to my controller method and use it to retrieve the request.

I thought that it would be a part of the spring-webmvc or the spring-web dependency

Thanks for the help and guidance

Answer (score 0):

To get the ip-address from the user use the [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and call the [`getRemoteAddr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()) method. To get access to the `HttpServletRequest` simply add it to the method as an argument.

```
@ResponseBody
public ReturnData downloadStart(@RequestBody DownloadStartVO startVO, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr(); // IP/Host of remote user
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Current date/time in millis
}
```

Something like the above should do the trick.

For a list of supported method arguments check [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) of the Spring Reference guide.

Comment: this is not a spring-mvc project. I know how to use the httpservletrequest. I wanted the dependancy for it. Tried adding spring-web as well as spring-webmvc as well as this <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
   <!--  <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency> but httpservletrequest class is not available

Comment: If it isn't a spring-mvc project then why on earth are you using the `@RequestBody` and `@ResopnseBody` annotations? Those are part of Spring MVC... If the class isn't available your dependencies are wrong.

Comment: It is a Rest controller no view is associated with it. So If I get @RequestHeader object can I expect the ip as a header??

Comment: Which is still Spring MVC (maybe you need to do some reading first?). Just inject the `HttpServletRequest` as mentioned regardless using rest or not is will work. Just use the right dependencies...

Comment: added dependencies to my q